# The upper bounds on rank $ 2 $ real matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, galois-theory, multilinear-algebra

Let $ A_{n}(F) $ be  the collection of all skew-symmetric matrices over the field $ F $ ($\operatorname{char} F \neq 2 $). Let M be a subspace of $ A_{n}(F) $ such that all non zero elements have rank $ 2 $ . Here we consider $ F = \mathbb{R} $  .
Then what will be the maximum dimension  of $ M $  when $ n = 6 $ ? I have already got $ \dim M \geq 5 $ .As if consider this subsapce
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & a & b & c & d & e \\ -a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\-b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\-c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\-d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\-e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array}\right]$$
where $ a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R} $ or . So in this space any element of is of rank $ 2 $.
Does it possible that $ \dim M = 6 $ or $ \geq 6 $ . I have also interested  in What will be the maximum dimension of $ M $ when $ n \geq 6 $ ( except $ n = 8 $).

Comment: There is a long history of avoiding rank 1, in the theory of elliptic pde; J. F. Adams, Peter D. Lax, Ralph S. Phillips, On Matrices Whose Real Linear Combinations are Nonsingular, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 16, No. 2 (Apr., 1965), pp. 318. But I don't know how to avoid rank 3.

Comment: @Ben Mckay , here the matrices are skew symmetric  so rank must be even .

Comment: I think  in general  the maximum  dimension of $M$ will be $\geq n-1$ also, as we can proceed in similar  way.

Comment: Here's a paper about spaces of skew-symmetric matrices with constant rank: [Boralevi, Faenzi, Mezzetti, *Linear spaces of matrices of constant rank and instanton bundles*, arXiv:1207.6299](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6299). That specific paper is about matrices of corank $2$ rather than rank $2$ but hopefully it gives a starting point to find further references.

Comment: @Zach Teitler  , I think they are interested  in complex number field .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A skew-symmetric matrix of rank 2 is of the form $(uv^T-vu^T)$ for some column vectors $u$ and $v$. Let's denote it $u\wedge v$. Also, if $u, v, w, z$ are linearly independent then $u\wedge v+w\wedge z$ has rank 4. It follows that a subspace of ${\mathfrak{so}}(n)$ consisting of matrices of rank $\leq 2$ is of the form $u\wedge V_0$ where $V_0$ is a subspace of ${\mathbb R}^n$, which we can assume lies in the orthogonal complement to ${\mathbb R}u$. In particular, the maximum dimension is $(n-1)$.

Comment: The maximum dimension is $n-1$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: can you provide me a prove for this ?Does the statement  true for any field?

Comment: I thought my answer gave a proof! Is there something missing?